# How to add tags dynamically in Aframe webvr

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

What i want to do is on Click of a image i want to dynamically add a image on the scene. The problem is that the tag  gets added but i am not able to attach a src attribute to it. I get this warning

> core:schema:warn  Unknown property `src` for component/system `undefined`.

What i want to do is when i click on the image i want a image to dynamically appear and when i click again it should be destroyed. Also i want to add a animation when the image is inserted like a fade in effect. Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="aframe.min.js"></script>
    <title>Web VR</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
            <img id="sky" src="sky.jpg">    
        </a-assets>
        <a-sky color="lightblue"></a-sky>
        <a-image id="a" src="aboutus.jpg" position="0 1.25 -4"></a-image>
        <a-camera position="0 0 3.8">
        <a-cursor id="cursor" color="red">
        </a-cursor>
        </a-camera>
    </a-scene>

<script>
var a=document.getElementById('a');
a.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var b=document. createElement('a-image');
    b.setAttribute('position','0 3.8 3.8');
    b.setAttribute('src','aboutus.jpg');
    a.appendChild(b);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would also really appreciate if someone could show me how to add the animation effect. Am just learning webvr and have been trying to figure this out since 3 days.

Comment: Ok i got this to work using document.createElementNS('','a-image'); 
But the problem am now getting is i am unable to see it. In the console if i inspect it is added below the Existing <a-image> But i cannot see the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem before, and the solution is twofold :

1. You need to wrap your a-scene manipulation code inside a window.load event
2. You need to slightly adjust the format of your .setAttribute() call.

   ```
   window.addEventListener("load", initAFrame);

   let addedImage;

   function initAFrame(){

       let a = document.getElementById("a");
       a.addEventListener("click", createDestroyImage.bind(true, a));

   }

   function createDestroyImage(a){

       if(addedImage){
           a.removeChild(addedImage);
           addedImage = null;
       } else {
           let b = document.createElement("a-image");
           b.setAttribute("position", {
               "x" : 0,
               "y" : 3.8,
               "z" : 3.8
           });
           a.appendChild(b);
           addedImage = b;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much @PookageHayes. This worked perfectly. Just that i had to change the position attribute like this b.setAttribute('position','0 3.8 3.8'); I have changed the code to include the following and it is working perfectly.   
 b.setAttribute('position','3 1.25 -4');
b.setAttribute("src","aboutus.jpg")

Also is there a way i can animate it while it comes and goes? This would be very helpful to me.

Comment: You may need to look into the <a-animation> entity for that.  Have a play and come back if you have any trouble!

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/core/animations.html#sidebar

Comment: in the else statement i added another element a-animation and set the following properties. c.setAttribute("id","a-ani"); c.setAttribute("begin",""); c.setAttribute("easing","ease-in"); c.setAttribute("attribute","scale"); c.setAttribute("from","0 0 0"); c.setAttribute("to","2 2 2"); c.setAttribute("dur","1000"); I then appended it as a child to the a-image.This works fine when the image is created on click.I get the effect as if its zooming into existance. But while deleting the image ie on clicking again i am unable to get the same reverse effect.I added the reverse code in if

Comment: that would be because the element is being removed before the animation has played - you can solve this problem either by adding a setTimeout to wait until the animation has finished, or add a 'animationend' listener to the animation, and remove the element only when that fires.

Comment: I added the setTimeout function and tried. It waits 1000 ms before it is destroyed but still no animation. Maybe something i should write specific in the begin attribute?